# Kohana: запрос ORM с вложенным условием

Tags: orm, kohana, mysql

Как выполнить в ORM запрос в скобках (5 строка).

```
SELECT bla bla bla from `db`
WHERE `direction` = '1' 
AND `date` >= 1357037100 
AND `date` <= 1378201500 
AND (`src` LIKE '%777%'  OR `dst` LIKE '%777%') 
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретно пятая строчка реализуется с использованием `where_open()` и `where_close()`, которые можно найти в статье [Знакомимся с Query Builder](http://kohanaframework.su/database/query_builder).

Выглядеть это будет так:

```
...
->where_open()
    ->where('src', ...)
    ->or_where('dst', ...)
->where_close()
...
```

FYI: `where_open()`, `where_close()` и `where()` являются алиасами для `and_where_open()`, `and_where_close()` и `and_where()` соответственно.

Answer (score 1):

Как работает ORM популярно написано тут http://kohana3.ru/module/orm

Если непонятен какой-то конкретный момент, то уточните его.

Comment: да, а еще тут http://kohanaframework.su/database/orm_basics_select и тут http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/orm

но нигде информации о запросе с условием нет. меня интересует конкретно 5 строка кода

Answer (score 0):

```
->where('somevalue', 'like', '123')
```